# multi dimensional list with a list as one of the dimensions

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, struct

I am going though many similar Makefiles that contain the same source code.  I am trying to figure out how many projects a particular source file exist in.
what I want is something like:

foo.c     4      [projA, projB, projC, projD]

bar.c     1      [projC]

it seems like I need a new lstOfProjects for each makefile and all 'Im doing is erasing it.
I have tried many other ways around it
can a tuple have a a list as one of it's elements?

```
for file in listOf Makefiles
for line in Makeifle
find code file (.c or .h)


    try:
        index = lstFilenames.index(strFilename)     # to determine if I have seen this file name yet
        #  Yes the file name is already in list
        lstOfFile = lstProjectNames[index]          # get list of projects that this file is seen in
        try:
            fileIndex = lstOfFile.index(myProject)  # check to see if the project is in the project list
        except:  # project not in list
            lstCount[index] +1                      # add one to count - I am counting the number of projects this file appears
            lstOfProjects.append(myProject)         # append the new project to list
    except:   # file name not found in list
            lstFilenames.append (strFilename)       #  put file in file name list 
            lstCount.append(1)                      # set count to one 
            lstOfProjects.append(myProject)         # add project name to project list

#************************************************************************** End of makefile  
lstProjectNames.append(lstOfProjects)  # add  project list to this list ( this list in indexed with teh file names and the counts)
del lstOfProjects[:]
```

Comment: even removing del, and moving lstProjectNames.append(lstOfProjects) under the last line of the second except. I still get incorrect answers.  I feel  like I can't get a new list of projects in my lstOfProjects  as if myProjects never gets a new list when I get a new file.  All of those variables are declared as <variable> =[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `del lstOfProjects[:]` line is the culprit, since your `lstProjectNames` is holding a [reference](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/pointers_and_references.html) to your `lstOfProjects` and once you delete its contents, its deleted in the `lstProjectNames`

Comment: I think I need a new lstOfProjects for each file.  how do I do that then?  Because all my files have the same list of Projects and I know that not to be true what I want is:  <br>                                                           CMD_AUTH.h        1 ['ARC', ]
Labortex.c           2 ['ARC', 'AFO']

Comment: Try replacing `del lstOfProjects[:]` with `lstOfProjects = []`
This will simply make your `lstOfProjects` variable point to a newly-created list in your program and the old one will stay safe in your `lstProjectNames`

Comment: Thanks Nether.That was the piece I was missing ( along with some minor logical issues) :)